# How do a maintain an accurate character count between input from separate fields using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a form to build a block of text, the final output of which needs to be kept under a certain character count.

For the user, I need to  be able to provide real-time character counting so they can adjust their entries as appropriate.

Basic HTML would be as follows:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="#input1">
  <input type="text" id="#input2">
</form>
<div class="character-counter">0</div>
```

However my JS/jQuery is not working very well: while it is outputting a counter in real time, it seems to be concatenating the final results in the output despite me parsing the variables as integers.

```
$('#input1').keyup(function() {
  // Variables
  var currentCharCount = parseInt($('.character-counter').text());
  var fieldLength = parseInt($(this).val().length, 10);
  var newCharCount = fieldLength + currentCharCount;
  // Counter output
  $('.character-counter').text(Number(newCharCount));
});

$('#input2').keyup(function() {
  // Variables
  var currentCharCount = parseInt($('.character-counter').text());
  var fieldLength = parseInt($(this).val().length, 10);
  var newCharCount = fieldLength + currentCharCount;
  // Counter output
  $('.character-counter').text(Number(newCharCount));
});
```

The correct solution will update the '.character-counter' div with the correct total character count between the fields every time a character is typed or deleted or pasted in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the old value of the `character-counter` element at all, you purely want to use the lengths of the text in the two inputs. Separately: Don't use `keyup`, use `input`. (What if the user right-clicks and pastes? No `keyup` occurs...)

Separately, the `id` attributes of your input fields are incorrect: They shouldn't have the `#` on them.

So (see comments):

```js
// You can hook the event on both fields with the same call
// Note using `input`, not `keyup`
$("#input1, #input2").on("input", function() {
    // Get the length of each input's current value, then put it
    // in the .character-counter div
    $('.character-counter').text($("#input1").val().length + $("#input2").val().length);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <!-- No # here --------^    -->
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <!-- Nor here ---------^    -->
</form>
<div class="character-counter">0</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, that worked perfectly! That all makes sense, I just didn't think to approach it from that perspective. Thanks so much